# Increase Slug Limit from 28 in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, slug

So I need to have longer slug lengths, over the 28 character limit.

I tried the filter option available on the previous post for this question with no success. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you link us to that question? Is this a WooCommerce-specific issue, i.e. the slug limit is in WooCommerce, or is it in WordPress? (I don't think I've seen it before, and note that WooCommerce-specific questions are probably better asked to their support routes than here sorry.) Is it a limit on the database column width too?

Comment: Was it [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/346089/3276)? I think we concluded there you'd need to change the database column width and edit register_taxonomy in core to increase this, and core edits aren't a great idea unless you manage them well e.g. by automatically patching core updates as they're applied. I don't think there's a filter there to solve this though - the filter in one of the answers just cuts the longer names down to 26 characters.

Comment: You have [Longer Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/longer-permalinks/) that increases the slug limit, have you tried it?